# adaptive precision algorithm/equation

Tags: ios, algorithm, gps

I apologize if the title is vague, but I'm not exactly how to title my situation.  I am writing an app for iPhone that uses GPS.  In the `didUpdateLocations:` method, I test the location's horizontal accuracy against a variable of arbitrary size (I set it to 50, since that seemed like a good starting point).  If the horizontal accuracy is less than 50, then I save the location and increment a counter to indicate that the location was successfully collected.  If the horizontal accuracy doesn't pass the test, the location success counter gets decremented.  I've been trying to come up with an equation that will adjust the horizontal accuracy test value.

The problem is easy enough to solve, if you just use the counter for the accuracy test, but I was hoping for something less linear.  I'd like for the counter to be weighted in a sense, so that the accuracy test variable will approach zero quickly at first and then slow down as it gets closer.

I had something that worked kind of like this, but it would start to oscillate once the accuracy test variable became too precise for the GPS to match.  After that, it would just jump between values, like 1 and 80 or so.  Here's what it looks like:

```
int previousCounter = successCounter;

if (location.horizontalAccuracy < accuracy)
{
    // save location...
    successCounter++;
}
else
    successCounter--;

int direction = previousCounter - successCounter;
accuracy = 50 - direction * pow(successCounter, 2);
```

I've been fiddling with this thing for hours and can't seem to get something practical working and I tried searching google, but I'm not exactly sure what to look for.  I'm hoping someone here can help.

Comment: How about increasing accuracy by a certain percentage when it is too small, and decreasing it by a certain percentage when it is too large?

Comment: Thanks for your input.  I ended up solving the problem without any fancy equations.  I'll post my solution so this thing can be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just using the linear approach for this, without the equation.  I may end up weighting the successCounter increments, just to tweak it a little.  In the end, the linear approach was more than sufficient for what I was trying to achieve, which I discovered after I did a field test with the app.  When I thought about it, this didn't even really achieve what I was trying to achieve, so that's why I ended up using the linear approach.  I had originally intended for this algorithm to be provide adaptive accuracy for the GPS, but I came to the realization that it is really only good for providing information about how accurate the current reading is.  Slight fail :/